# "No such file or directory" error on reload command in nginx

Tags: nginx

When issuing the command

```
# nginx -s reload
```

I get the following error:

> nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

I don't understand the message – what is the reason for it?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more accessible: a more concise title, removing all the typos, and proper markdown for code (in backticks) and the error message (as a quote, using `>`). I also tried adding an actual question, your original wording only said that you don't understand the error, but there was no question. I think the question could still be improved by adding more context, maybe pointing out if there is anything special about your setup or the like.

Answer (score 6):

The `nginx -s reload` co sends `reload` signal to currently running nginx process.
Firstly, nginx tries to find PID file, which should be located `/run/nginx.pid` (I guess, this path is shown in your `nginx.conf`).
Secondly, nginx tries to read PID of currently running nginx process from that file and send `HUP` signal to that process (it's a request to reload configuration).

In your case, nginx cannot find `/run/nginx.pid` file. It's probably caused by two reasons: 1. there is no currently running nginx process, 2. the PID file is located in different a location instead of the path, which is shown in `nginx.conf`.

You should check an existence of nginx process, for example, you can use `ps aux | grep nginx`. If there is no any nginx process, then that is the answer to your question. Also, you should check path to PID file in your configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

I fix it by removing `nginx.pid` in `/usr/local/var/run`